# Как обрезать массив php на части по значениям из другого массива?

Tags: php, массивы, регулярные-выражения

Я получаю массив при помощи `file('file.txt')`, файл такого вида:

```
"понедельник, 21 августа
...
...
вторник
...
...
среда, 23 августа
..."
```

Мне нужно разбить массив по дням недели (массив регулярных выражений):

```
$days = array(
        '/^Понедельник+/',
        '/^Вторник+/',
        '/^Среда+/',
        '/^Четверг+/',
        '/^Пятница+/',
        '/^Суббота+/',
        '/^Воскресенье+/',
);
```

Если будет 7 дней, то file() превратится в 7 массивов. Я могу найти ключи дней недели при помощи preg_grep, которые встречаются в file()... Если бы нужно было сделать 2 массива из одного, то можно использовать array_slice. Но что делать, если их может быть от 7 штук?

Comment: Не очень понятно что есть и что надо получить. Добавьте пару примеров входных и выходных (ожидаемых) значений.

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи. Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, просьба не забывать помечать его как ответ! Это важно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно так, до совершенства доведете сами:

```
<?php

$array[0] = 'Понедельник день';
$array[1] = '12';
$array[2] = '12';
$array[3] = 'Вторник день';
$array[4] = '45';
$array[5] = '45';
$array[6] = 'Среда день';
$array[7] = '789';
$array[8] = '789';
$array[9] = '789';

$now = -1;
$response = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     if (preg_match('/^Понедельник+|^Вторник+|^Среда+/', $value)) {
          $now++;
     }else{
          if ($now > -1)
               $response[$now][] = $value;
     }
}
print_r($response);
```

Дальше сами разберетесь, ответ такой:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
            [1] => 45
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 789
            [1] => 789
            [2] => 789
        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

Приветствую! Возможно решение не самое изящное, если что, доработайте сами! ;)

Текст в файле:

```
Понедельник, 21 августа
Сервер работает
Вторник, 22 августа
Сервер упал
Среда, 23 августа
Сервер работает
Сервер работает
Среда, 24 августа
Сервер упал
Вторник, 25 августа
```

---

```
$text_arr = file("t.txt");
$days = [
    '/^Понедельник+/',
    '/^Вторник+/',
    '/^Среда+/',
    '/^Четверг+/',
    '/^Пятница+/',
    '/^Суббота+/',
    '/^Воскресенье+/',
];

$keys = [];
$result = [];

/**
 * Перебираем массив паттернов и проверяем вхождения по тексту
 * отсекая пустые элементы, и записываем в $keys порядковый номер строки с датой
 * Все последующие id между ними, наши будущие массивы с текстом.
 * На выходе получаем массив вида:
 * [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(9) [3]=> int(4) [4]=> int(7) ...
 */
foreach ($days as $day):
    $search = preg_grep($day, $text_arr);
    if (!empty($search)):
        foreach ($search as $id => $chunk):
            array_push($keys, $id);
        endforeach;
    else:
        continue;
    endif;
endforeach;

/** Сортируем массив по значениям, по порядку, т.к. парсить текст мы будем сверху вниз */
sort($keys);

/**
 * Увеличиваем наши id на 1, для того чтобы не включать даты в результат
 * Обрезаем массив по отступу, где стартовым отступом будет найденный выше id,
 * а длинной отступа будет разница, между id следующего элемента и текущего.
 */
foreach ($keys as $id => $key):
    ++$key;
    if (++$id != count($keys)):
        array_push($result, array_slice($text_arr, $key, next($keys) - $key));
    else:
        array_push($result, array_slice($text_arr, $key));
    endif;
endforeach;
```

---

Результат:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "Сервер работает"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(23) "Сервер упал"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "Сервер работает
"
    [1]=>
    string(31) "Сервер работает"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(23) "Сервер упал"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```